# How can I refresh page when APP wake from backstage or Unlock

Tags: javascript, android, html, ios, vue.js

My VUE project is embedded in the app,there is a problem.

I wrote an update program function that will display the update progress bar in the pop-up window. This progress bar is reported by the device.

When the update program is executing, I press the Home button,APP drops in backstage,and then,I wake up the App,the `van-progress` is Stopped.

Turning off the screen during the update process can also cause this problem. The update progress bar stops the progress when the screen is turned off. Although the device has been updated, the page is stuck.

What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implement onPause and onResume in your activity.
onPause will be called when ever you "leave" your activity, either when you lock phone or "minimize" it.
In the onPause you can save the state you are currently in.
onResume occurs once when you first start your app (after onCreate) and is called again when ever your app is resumed, which happens when you enter it again after putting it in the background or when you unlock your phone (in case you locked your phone when your activity was active)

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
}
```

In the onPause you can set a boolean indicating you were in the middle of a progress bar showing and in the onResume you can check for the indicator, if it's true you can just show the progress bar again